# Use string literal instead of header name in Pandas csv file manipulation

Tags: python, pandas

Python 3.9.5/Pandas 1.1.3

I use the following code to create a nested dictionary object from a csv file with headers:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import os

csv = "/Users/me/file.csv"
csv_file = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=",", header=0, index_col=False)
csv_file['org'] = csv_file[['location', 'type']].apply(lambda s: s.to_dict(), axis=1)
```

This creates a nested object called `org` from the data in the columns called `location` and `type`.

Now let's say the `type` column doesn't even exist in the csv file, and I want to pass a literal string as a `type` value instead of the values from a column in the csv file.  So for example, I want to create a nested object called `org` using the values from the `data` column as before, but I want to just use the string `foo` for all values of a key called `type`.  How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just build it *by hand*:

```
csv_file['org'] = csv_file['location'].apply(lambda x: {'location': x,
                                                        'type': 'foo'})
```

Comment: Hi - I like that this uses less code than the other answer - but can you help me with putting it in the context of my code.  For example, when I try to implement your suggestion into my code, I'm getting errors around the `s.to_dict()` and `axis=1` arguments.

Comment: @Stpete111: this is already in the context of your own code. Did you try it *as is*?

Comment: Sorry about that, I had assumed I still needed to consider the other arguments in addition to your code.  It does work, and it does so in a nice pythonic way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use `Chainmap`. This will allow to use multiple columns  (`columns_to_use`), and even override existing ones (if `type` is in these columns, it will be overridden):

```
from collections import ChainMap

# .. some code
csv_file['org'] = csv_file[columns_to_use].apply(
    lambda s: ChainMap({'type': 'foo'}, s.to_dict()), axis=1)
```

BTW, without adding constant values it could be done by `df.to_dict()`:

```
csv_file['org'] = csv_file[['location', 'type']].to_dict('records')
```

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify - assume that there isn't actually a column called `type` in the csv file and I'm trying to create that secondary key:value from scratch, where the key is `type` and the value is `foo`..  In this case, will your code still work?  (I have updated my question to clarify this).

Comment: @Stpete111 it will still work. Just drop it from the list of columns. Updated the answer to reflect that

Comment: Ok so it's not going to give me an error for the column `type` not existing in the csv file?  I will try it now...

Comment: I'm getting `maximum recursion level reached` error.  Trying to diagnose now...

Comment: Ok, recursion error was on me - too many square brackets.  But now getting a lambda error.